# Accuracy of iPhone timestamps (NSDate) relative to global clock?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

We're keeping our backend servers in sync using NTP but are not sure how synchronized are the time stamps retrieved on the fronted (using NSDate). Can you please comment if you have experience with this issue?

Comment: If the date/time is important to you, do not trust the client timestamp. In general, if data is important to you, don't trust *anything* the client sends you.

Comment: The value from `[NSDate date]` is as accurate as the phone's internal clock.  Date values sent from outside are as accurate as they are.  Usually, when a phone is communicating with a cell tower, the clock will be subsecond accurate, but users can turn off that feature, or the cell tower can be out of range (or you may be on a pod or pad and not a phone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, although often it can be fairly close, from time to time it can be inaccurate by several seconds, and the offset vary even over several hours.

Also, the tower time it syncs to can be off, I've seen 15 seconds, 60 seconds (for months), and once : 1 hour when daylight savings was applied when it shouldn't have been.  Once it isn't syncing to the tower it can drift 10s of seconds per day, and worse when "off".